# Crash when c# Outlook Addin use funtion in c++ library

Tags: c#, c++, outlook

I have written a outlook addin that loads c++ library,the addin could see functions in the library but when using, it crashed.

This is my c++ library code:

// TestDLL.h

```
#pragma once

using namespace System;

namespace TestDLL {

public ref class MyClass
{
public:
    int Add(int a, int b);
};
}
```

// TestDLL.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include "TestDLL.h"

namespace TestDLL  {

int MyClass::Add(int a, int b) 
{
    return a + b;
}
}
```

And this is my addin code:

```
using TestDLL;

public partial class ThisAddIn
{
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Test));
        t.Start();
    }

    private void Test()
    {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        int res = myClass.Add(12, 25);

        MessageBox.Show("res:" + res);

    }

    private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

}

If I try with c# form application, it works. So what's going here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook's bitness should correspond to the unmanaged DLL bitness. You can't load x86 dll into x64 process.